# Not able to get the metrics from prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, prometheus

In my kubernetes cluster one node (node1)is ubuntu and the another node(node2) is a virtual machine running inside node1. I am able to get prometheus metric from node1, but not from node 2. While i am issuing get pods command i am able to see my pods running on node 2, but i coudn't get the metric information.

Is this my Vmware issue / Cluster /Prometheus issue. how to resolve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you share Prometheus configuration (`prometheus.yaml`) file?

Comment: Odd pattern here (a k8s node in a virtual machine within a k8s node): what are you trying to achieve with it? If you just want to experiment, what about picking a [local machine solution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#local-machine-solutions) with multi-node capabilities like [kubeadm-dind-cluster](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubeadm-dind-cluster)?